# In Unity3D, How to make the whole scene in dark, but some Area are not in dark

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wan't make some teaching levels with UGUI, so need the whole to be in dark, but some rectangular area not in dark.

I can make the whole scene in dark by adding a gameobject with a image component, and control it's alpha to dark.

But I don't know how to make some rectangular area to be lighted, and the rectangular will change in different teaching levels. And different device with different resolution will also change the rec's bounder.

Picutre3 is what I wanted, and just rectangular area is OK.

Picture1
[image: P1]

Picture2

[image: P2]

Picture3

[image: P3]

Picture4
[image: P4]

Comment: I did a similar thing a while ago and I did it by making a masking shader. What I do is I first render the Scene with only the masks (in your case a single rectangle) to a render texture as white. Everywhere on the texture where there is nothing else I just render black. Then I blend this texture with the final render. This might be overlkill for you but it will allow you to have many rectangles or even arbitrary shapes later on. If you need more guidance I will post a full answer with example code when I have the time.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try it, and it would be the best if you have the time to post the full answer.

Comment: I added the answer. I realised that you might want a 3D type of effect instead (almost like shining a flash light from above). If this is the case I will extend the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll explain how you can achieve this with a simple shader and some setup. I'm speaking from memory so if some problems occur please ask.

So what you can do is:

- Make a new layer for rendering the masks. Let's say we call this layer MaskLayer.
- Duplicate your main camera. We call the old main camera camA and the new one camB.
- Set camA's culling mask to include everything except for MaskLayer.
- Set camB's culling mask to only include MaskLayer.
- Create a new render texture (let's say MaskRT) and set it to be the render target for camB.
- Now create any game object. Let's make it a sprite with a solid colour (white).
- Set the layer of the sprite to MaskLayer.

At this point you should notice that the sprite is no longer visible in the Game window or in the camA preview. Only the rest of the scene is visible. When you select camB then only the plane will be visible in the preview. The output from camB represents where the "holes" will be.

Now we continue with this:

- Create a new sprite that is as large as the viewport.
- Ensure that this sprite has the default tag.
- Create a new shader and a new material. Call it MaskMaterial. The
  default shader template that is created should be good enough. I don't remember exactly what it provides but it should have at least a texture input.
- Lets say your shader parameter is called DIFFUSE. In the pixel
  shader, set the output colour to something like:

  ```
  fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
  {
      fixed4 texcol = tex2D (DIFFUSE, i.uv);
      fixed4 outputColor = fixed4(0,0,0, 0.8-texcol.r);
      return outputColor ;
  }
  ```

So what we say here in our shader in plain English is:
My color is solid black with slight transparency (0.8) unless my input texture has a white color at the same position, in which case I am more transparent (-texcol.r).

We use the r component here but you can just as easily use any color component.

Now assign this new material and shader to your full screen sprite and set your MaskRT render texture as the input texture DIFFUSE for the Mask Shader.

If everything went well (lol right) then you should now have your desired effect. Moving the mask is now as easy as moving any objects in the scene that are marked with the MaskLayer layer. So you can have many masks.

NOTES:

- The sprite might make things difficult for you some perhaps start out
  with a plane that faces the camera just in case.
- Here is the docs on shaders in case you need some reading there:http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ShaderTut2.html It's worth looking into but you can probably get away with trial and error this time.

  - In your shader there will probably a Color input by default. You can use this in the fragment shader instead of saying (0,0,0..) for easier and more control over the resulting mask. This will allow you to change your masking appearance as usual with the sliders of the material. For example:

  fixed4 outputColor = fixed4(InputColor.Albedo, InputColor.a-texcol)

EDIT:
You can have a look at the "Using shader properties in Cg code" section here:http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ShaderTut2.html You can copy paste this entire piece and change the fragment shader if you are struggling (sorry I don't know what level of experience you have with it).

EDIT:
Here is the shader as requested. Also read the following notes.

```
Shader "Tutorial/Textured Colored" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,0.5)
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" { }
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags
        {
          "Queue" = "Transparent"
        }

        Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass {

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        fixed4 _Color;
        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct v2f {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        float4 _MainTex_ST;

        v2f vert (appdata_base v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
            o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX (v.texcoord, _MainTex);
            return o;
        }

         fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 texcol = tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv);
            fixed4 outputColor = _Color;
            outputColor.a -= texcol.r;
            return outputColor ;
        }
        ENDCG

        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- This shader should go on your full screen quad.
- Note the difference in shader property names (instead of DIFFUSE it is now the more clear _Color and _MainTex.
- The logic remains about the same.
- This code is not tested.
- There are more efficient ways to do this for example writing only the masking object depth to a single channel RenderTexture but this way is easier to learn I think.
- Once you get this semi-working there are several improvements to be made. The first would be to change the mask rectangles' material to one with an unlit solid color shader.

UPDATE:

I left out crucial parts of the shader sorry. Please see the Tags section and the Blend operation added to the shader. Also please note that for the full screen quad you should rather use a plane and NOT a sprite as the shader is not compatible with sprites in this state.

Also note that in the example project here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw8X8yAt21AiYjRyVkxJUkhreVU/view?usp=sharing

that the plane is flipped both in the x and z axes.

As for the UGUI part that I missed earlier - This solution MIGHT work. I have not checked. If the mask is behind the UI you can try to set the "Queue" tag in the shader to "Overlay".

Comment: Sorry, I am not so good at shader, and I tried, but failed. Could you give me a completed shader,  if it's more convenient. Thanks

Comment: Okay I updated the answer. If you still struggle you will have to give more details on the problem. Problems can range from the scene setup to syntax errors in the shader so it is hard to guess what is wrong. Maybe come back and post a screenshot of the latest result (if it runs but doesn't work correctly).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm trying it.

Comment: Be sure to use the MaskRT as the input texture of your mask shader.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you so many times. And sorry for my inexperienced u3d. I was working this with UGUI, but I notice that your method is not for UI. So I new a project to try to find some ways, but it doesn't work correctly. Picture1 and Picture2 are the setting of my project, and when I run it, the Mask layer will not show. Is there something wrong? Picture3 is what I want, and just rectangular area is OK, and I want it can mask UGUI also. If you are busy, you can ignore this, so sorry for disturbing you so many times.

Comment: It's not a problem that is what we are here for. Okay yes to work with UI this solution will require many more adjustments. I think the next thing I must do is to make a working example project that you can just unzip and see how it works. This will take some time but I think it's the best way forward from here.

Comment: My weak English can't describe my appreciation for you. Thank you very much.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw8X8yAt21AiYjRyVkxJUkhreVU/view?usp=sharing   Here is an example I made for you real quick. When you run the scene test1.unity you can move the SolidWhite sprite to move the mask. When I wrote the instructions I missed some crucial details so I'll update the answer

Comment: Sorry, look at Picture4, did I miss something? Or would you Export Package, I am afraid that I missed something.

Comment: Let's continue the discussion in the chat please.